# Is it possible to decimate or unsubdivide only a part of mesh?

Tags: modeling

Would it perhaps be possible to *un-subdivide* the lower part of a mesh, in this case, for a human, so that the facial details are preserved while the body details are lowered in poly count?

I'm imaging some sort of algorithm which employs `edge loop reduction` techniques like these:
[image]

Certainly the solution would not be perfectly elegant. Even if it required manual cleanup, the preservance of detail would be worth it I believe.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, it is possible to decimate, but not unsubdivide.

In decimate, you can set up a vertex group, which can be used to set a part of the mesh, that should be decimated:

[image]

[image]

To unsubdivide I don't see any possible ways to do this without splitting object into 2 parts and joining back after unsubdividing

Comment: I would just like to confirm that splitting the object in 2, then subdividing works REALLY well. the unsubdivide function works well to maintain the structure of the vertices around areas that have been split - meaning that the rejoin process is REALLY straightforward. The total time it takes to do the entire procedure would be at most 10 minutes per hole

Comment: Note that I havent checked yet how the process will affect UV's